# Using time_t filttering

Tags: c++, oop, c++-chrono, time-t

I'd like to understand better time_t since i've never dealt with it before.

I want to make a filter_by_time function that gets a time window (lets say, 24 hours) and sends me back a vector of objects with a lower time gap of the said time window.

So since the function is getting a integer (from what i googled i understand i might need long-int) how can i convert the current time and the time_t field of an object into a long int ?

I was thinking to check if the current time (now) minus object's time_t  < 24 hours then i'd put object into the array

hope i could be clear enough with my ambitions

Comment: `time_t` is already an integer? A [mre] of what you're trying to achieve and what exact problem you've encountered might help explain your question better. You might find [std::chrono](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) easier to use than `time_t`

Comment: _"the function is getting a integer"_ - what function is that? We need more info. Please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

Actually the `time_t` is almost always an integer counting the seconds since 00:00, Jan 1 1970 UTC (POSIX time).

However, this is not defined by the standard and might not be 100% reliable everywhere.

You can try to use [from_time_t](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock/from_time_t) to convert your `time_t` to a [time_point](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point/time_point) and use the constructors of `time_point` and [duration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/duration) to construct another time point from your integer. Then you can compare those time points.

This would be the most reliable way of solving the problem without assuming any particular format for time `time_t`.

But if it is acceptable for you to assume that the `time_t` is always POSIX time, you might also be able to just substract the integers as you have already suggested.